# Periodically I can't create GCP task because of java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-tasks

I create tasks as it described in https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks

It works in 99% cases, but sometimes i get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper$ManagedChannelReference.<init> (ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:103)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init> (ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:53)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.<init> (ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper.java:44)
at io.grpc.internal.AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.build (AbstractManagedChannelImplBuilder.java:411)
at by.company.application.QueueService.createTask (QueueService.java:76)
```

Code of method inside QueueService:

```
 private void createTask(String queueName, String payload, long timeShiftMillis) {
String queuePath = QueueName.of(gcpProjectId, gcpLocation, queueName).toString();

try (CloudTasksClient client = CloudTasksClient.create()) {
    Task.Builder taskBuilder = Task
            .newBuilder()
            .setAppEngineHttpRequest(AppEngineHttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setBody(ByteString.copyFrom(payload, Charset.defaultCharset()))
                    .setRelativeUri("/" + queueName)
                    .setHttpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
                    .build());

    taskBuilder.setScheduleTime(Timestamp
            .newBuilder()
            .setSeconds(Instant.now(Clock.systemUTC()).plusMillis(timeShiftMillis).getEpochSecond()));

    Task build = taskBuilder.build();

    if (!gcpTaskEnabled) {
        return;
    }

    client.createTask(queuePath, build);
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Can't create task", e);
}
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Channel ManagedChannelImpl was not shut down properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481760/channel-managedchannelimpl-was-not-shut-down-properly)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/3648. Try upgrading to the latest version of google-cloud-tasks (and of it's dependencies) to get the fix.

Comment: I use following version: <gcp.version>0.81.0-alpha</gcp.version>
And it doesn't help :(