# How to prevent ManagedChannelImpl error without using try-with-resources?

Tags: java, client, grpc

We get this error while using Google's `SecretManagerServiceClient`.

```
i.g.i.ManagedChannelOrphanWrapper *~*~*~ Channel ManagedChannelImpl{logId=1, target=secretmanager.googleapis.com:443} was not shutdown properly!!! ~*~*~*
    Make sure to call shutdown()/shutdownNow() and wait until awaitTermination() returns true.
java.lang.RuntimeException: ManagedChannel allocation site
```

The javadocs say:

> Note: close() needs to be called on the SecretManagerServiceClient object to clean up resources such as threads. In the example above, try-with-resources is used, which automatically calls close().

This makes sense, but this would require each instance of each service to create and destroy a client for each request for a secret. We have lots of secrets so it makes sense to only create one client and use dependency injection to use it whenever it's needed. Is there a better solution here, or do I need to just do what the docs say and not worry about performance/network costs of creating/destroying countless GRPC clients?

I have looked at these answers which say to close/shutdown the client when you're done using it. Mostly the same as the javadocs.

[Channel ManagedChannelImpl was not shut down properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481760/channel-managedchannelimpl-was-not-shut-down-properly)

Comment: The error message indicates that the ManagedChannelImpl had been garbage collected, so you aren't using the same instance as you expect.  Have you verified that based upon the allocation site it is the channel you expect that is generating this error?